# Magento2 AWS Disk Space is always full after some time

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento2.4 on AWS and after every 6 7 hours cache folder takes all the memory
it always has 25 30 GB of cache data on sever and I have to delete it manually or clear the cache from Magento Backend
How to solve this problem

Comment: Do you use redis? Varnish.. what is your stack..

Comment: no, I am not using redis or varnish

Comment: PHP 7.4 fpm apach2, mysql 8, elastic search, and normal magento2.4 requirement nothing extra problem with cache it is taking memory all the time I have to clear cache 3 4 times in a day

Comment: can you give an idea of the content that is in your cache?

Comment: There are random files in var/cache/ and folders mage--0 to mage--9 and more and these folder has random number like mage---124_4DFED36154E3CE2BD10EC56215FF7DBB912842CE
i have cleared the cache like 1 hour and now it has 4 GB of data in the cache folder

Comment: Let’s wait to hear of more thoughts from other users.. you might add details like catalog size, number of urls in your site map.. anything giving us a clue on what is the content and why it gets so big

Comment: almost 3500 sku it was working fine before I just shifted to aws and I am facing this problem